# Getting Google Maps to Work with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I cant seem to get markers to populate on my google maps using angularJS

**HTML**

```
<section class="module module-divider-bottom p-0" style="height: 500px;" ng-controller="LocationsController">
  <div id="map"></div>
</section>
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
angular.module('cuApp')
.controller('LocationsController',
    [
        '$scope', 'LocationsService', '$compile',
        function($scope, locationsService, $compile) {

            $scope.map = '';
            $scope.model = {
                canvasLocationsData: [],
                canvasLocationMarkers: []
            };

            locationsService.GetCanvasLocations().then(function(response) {
                    if (response.data) {
                        $scope.model.canvasLocations = response.data;

                        angular.forEach(response.data.response.locations,
                            function(value, key) {
                                if (value.locatorType === "S") {
                                    $scope.model.canvasLocationsData.push(value);
                                    var tempArry = [];
                                    tempArry.push(value.institutionName);
                                    tempArry.push(value.latitude);
                                    tempArry.push(value.longitude);
                                    $scope.model.canvasLocationMarkers.push(tempArry);
                                }
                            });


                    }
                });

            function initialize() {
                var initLatLng = { lat: 39.742043, lng: -104.991531 };
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: initLatLng,
                    mapTypeControl: false
                };
                $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

                setMarkers($scope.map);
            }

            var locations = $scope.model.canvasLocationMarkers;

            function setMarkers(Map) {
                var icon = {
                    url: '/files/imgs/cnv_marker.png', 
                };
                for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
                    var location = locations[i];
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
                        map: Map,
                        icon: icon,
                        title: location[0]
                    });
                }
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        }
    ]);
```

The Locations look like this its an array of arrays:

```
0:["Canvas CU", "39.748500", "-104.997000"]
1:["Canvas CU", "39.745200", "-105.006000"]
2:["Canvas CU", "39.729300", "-104.941000"]
```

The map will successfully load on the html page, however the markers are not ever displayed. I'm not sure if this is because the call to get the markers data is coming in after the map has loaded and at the time of loading `$scope.model.canvasLocationMarkers` is empty or something is wrong with my code.

**JSFiddle:** Doesnt use AngularJS but still cant get the markers to display:
https://jsfiddle.net/n29au068/4/

Comment: Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/3J25M/413/

Comment: Can you add a console.log(locations.length) just before you iterate over the locations? Check if that is 0 or not. 

Another thing you can try is to remove icon:icon from the marker object you are creating, and checking if the default markers load.

Comment: Also, the reason your jsfiddle doesn't work is because you need to put map:map and not map:Map when you are creating your marker object in setMarkers

Answer (score 0):

you used function Map instead of local variable map
change it to lowercase map

```
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
        //map: Map,        is wrong
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: location[0],
```